# Google map API v3 version 3.37 causes "Out of stack space" while older versions did not

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We used google map API (js) for a long time without issues. Recently, we received the following crash 'Out of stack space' when we submit any form that contains a 'google place autocomplete' input.

```
Error: Out of stack space
  at open_now.get(/maps-api-v3/api/js/37/7/intl/en_gb/util.js:213:151)
  at open_now.get(/maps-api-v3/api/js/37/7/intl/en_gb/util.js:213:171)
  at open_now.get(/maps-api-v3/api/js/37/7/intl/en_gb/util.js:213:171)
  at open_now.get(/maps-api-v3/api/js/37/7/intl/en_gb/util.js:213:171)
  ....(thousands of recursive calls)
```

The crash started on Jul 11, 2019. When we check the logs, they are all from version 3.37 (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#337) while the older API versions are fine. We temporarily switch to an older version to avoid the crash (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=OLDER_VERSION&key=OUR_KEY), but it is not a long-term solution. Is there anyone met the same issue and any Google engineer can help take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue? The [autocomplete example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) doesn't exhibit the reported problem, so it is likely something you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has recently been fixed. This was also reported in Google's Public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137213536

The issue was due to the recent Maps JavaScript API version 3.37 rollover which was already fixed by Google engineers as per the public bug. If the error with the new version is still reproducible on your end, you can comment on the issue link above for the engineers to further investigate.